# When i run the Junit test case i am getting Noclassdeffounderror:Junit/framework/test

Tags: android, junit, robotium

Iam having one .apk

To test this using robotium, i have created one test app and in the test app i am calling the original app package.

When i run the junit test case, i am getting the below error..

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/framework/Test
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadTestLoaderClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createRawTestLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.defaultInit(RemoteTestRunner.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.init(RemoteTestRunner.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.framework.Test
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 3):

You may have failed to add the JUnit JAR to your runtime CLASSPATH.

You may have imported the wrong Test; maybe you have `org.junit.Test`.

`ClassNotFoundException` usually means CLASSPATH or import issues.

Comment: I have added junit.jar in the Run As --> Run Configuration --> Classpath --> Junit..jar (from the C:\Users\chandrasekaran\Desktop\eclipse-java-helios-SR1-win32\eclipse\plugins\org.junit_4.8.1.v4_8_1_v20100427-1100\junit.jar) under user entries.. Now i am getting                                                                                               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown....